# Error installing meteor accounts-entry package

Tags: javascript, meteor

Been trying to install the meteor accounts-entry package and I've got the following error.

Anyone know how I can sort this?  I've tried googling but didn't find anything.  I tried installing the node underscore.string package but that didn't make any difference.

> $ mrt add accounts-entry
>
> Done installing smart packages
>
> Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
>
> Done installing smart packages
>
> Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!
>
> => Errors while scanning packages:
>
> While building package `underscore-string-latest`:
>      error: File not found: lib/underscore.string/lib/underscore.string.js
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/command.js:41
>      throw "Command exited with " + code + "/" + signal;
>                                                        ^
>      Command exited with 1/null

When the app is run I get the following on the browser:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
node_modules/underscore.string/test/test_underscore/index.html:1: Can't set
DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/underscore.string/test/test.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.
(Meteor sets    <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/underscore.string/test/test_standalone.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.
(Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
```

I've not looked into the doctype error much yet, going to have a look into this a bit later on.

Thanks again in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added npm modules to your meteor project.

Delete the npm folder (in the current directory)

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

To use npm modules in your project see this instead: http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html

Comment: Yeah I only did that to see if that's what the problem could be, it wasn't.  May have been a connection problem when I was installing the package, got it working now.  Thank you, and thanks for the link too :)